# Add JPG image on PNG image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have two images. One JPG(small size) and another is PNG(large size).
I have to create another third JPG image by placing JPG(small size) image on PNG(large size) image and have to store that image in a folder. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You.

Comment: gd doesn't (usually) care what the image is. it doesn't deal with "jpg" or "png" internally. all images are converted to raw plain bitmaps in-memory. so start reading: http://php.net/gd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with this small image `small.jpg`

[image]

and this large image `large.png`

[image]

Running this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize('small.jpg');
   $src  = imagecreatefromjpeg('small.jpg');
   $dest = imagecreatefrompng('large.png');

   // Copy 
   imagecopy($dest, $src, 300, 20, 0, 0, $width, $height);

   // Write result 
   imagepng($dest,"result.jpg");
?>
```

gives this

[image]

Comment: Yes, It works for me. Thanks dude.. But where is the origin point? LEFT-BOTTOM or LEFT-TOP?

Comment: Glad it helped. Origin is top-left, try swapping the 300 and 20 around to see.